# SSAS - Moving Annual Total

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssas, mdx

Environment: SQL-Server-2005, SSAS 2005

I am using the following formula to create a Moving Annual Total

`SUM ({[Time].CurrentMember.Lag(3):[Time].CurrentMember}, [Measures].[TRx Quantity])`

The same column `[Measures].[Trx Quantity]` is used in other calculations and it works fine.  This one, however, comes up with `#Value!` to indicate some kind of an error. Can anyone point me in the proper direction here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be that I was missing the MONTH

SUM ({[Time].[Month].CurrentMember.Lag(3):[Time].[Month].CurrentMember}, [Measures].[TRx Quantity])

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in my answer. In SSAS 2005 (and above) your uniquename references should be in the form of [Dimension].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember and [Month] is a hierarchy of the [Time] dimension.

Comment: @Darren: In my time dimension, [Month] is not a hierarchy - it is just a regular column. It said something to the effect that it needs a hierarchy.  I tried creating a hierarchy and putting the name in, but then I used simple logic and figured out that it was asking me for a reference to the [Month]

Answer (score 2):

Is this SSAS 2005/2008?

If it is either of these and you are running this in Management Studio you can hover over the #Value and get the details of the error.

But at a guess it is most likely because .CurrentMember needs to be called on a hierarchy and `[Time]` is a dimension reference. It should refer to one of the hierarchies like `[Time].[Calendar].CurrentMember` or maybe `[Time].[Quarter].CurrentMember`